# Creating copy procedure for trigger

Tags: postgresql

I'm setting up triggers in PostgreSQL and I'm not sure how make certain cases. For example I set up table films and some endpoint changes any part that it should create exact copy if row edited before change and save it to films_log. And also if few rows changes I need that those rows would log too.

```
CREATE TABLE films (
  id          integer PRIMARY KEY,
  title       varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  did         integer NOT NULL,
  date_prod   date,
  kind        varchar(10)
);


CREATE TABLE films_log (
  serial      integer,
  title       varchar(200),
  did         integer,
  date_prod   date,
  kind        varchar(200)
);

CREATE TRIGGER films_logging_trigger 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON myschema.films 
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE films_logging();
```

What I tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION films_logging() RETURNS trigger
            LANGUAGE plpgsql
            AS $$
            BEGIN
            INSERT INTO films_log (id, title, did, date_prod, kind)
            SELECT id, title, did, date_prod, kind FROM films WHERE id = OLD.id
            END;
            $$;
```

Comment: I just found out that it requires return which It should return anything

Comment: shouldn't*. Typo

Comment: Is it possible to make it Void type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger functions **have** to return a row. In a `before` trigger, that is usually the `new` row.

You also don't need the `SELECT`, using the values from the `old` row directly is more efficient:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION films_logging() RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO films_log (id, title, did, date_prod, kind)
  values (old.id, old.title, old.did, old.date_prod, old.kind);

  return new; --<< here
END;
$$;
```